# NW.js Button injection

Tags: web-scraping, webkit, nw.js

I would like to build an app with NW.js which will assist the user with automatic Form filling (json files on the machine). I wish to add a button to any page loaded by the webkit browser, but coming from desktop app with IE ActiveX I'm a little bit lost about where I can hook my function to inject a "Fill" button in any page loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first things first, I want to ensure that you are writing a secure application.

The problem with using NW.js for loading webpages is that the browser context has access to the nodejs api, enabling malicious code on a webpage loaded by NW.js full access to the NW.js client's host machine, including filesystem and code execution.

The solution to this is to create either an iframe with the `nwdisable` attribute, or the newish webview element, and use that as the user's "browser".

Once you have that, you can inject javascript into the frame with:

```
 Window.eval(frame, script)
```

For documentation on `Window.eval`:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Window#windowevalframe-script

For notes on security and using iframe/webview with nwdisable:

http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Security%20in%20NW.js/

Comment: I understand what you mean, I navigate only on few sites which could always contain malicious code but which normally could be considered as secure. I experienced some integration of one of them in the past in an iframe but saddly its javascript is considering to be running at the top level and doesn't work correctly in an iframe.... so if I understand well I will be obliged to use the webview. I thank you for pointing me to some doc I didn't yet discover. Ok I hope I could success and get rid of the activeX and unify or development around web tools only. Many thanks

Comment: it is also possible to add the option "nodejs": false, to your package.json file if you don't need node at all.

Comment: No I think I will need Node to be able to store some data and As I said I got the data to fill the form with on the machine..